# Creating a List type using long instead of int for count

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, int, long-integer

I am trying to create a table using a datagrid that can have up to 8 billion elements. I've managed to use a Virtual collection to get quick processing - so that is not an issue. The virtualizing collection, however, implements IList, which uses an INT for the count value. My problem is once I hit 2^32 elements the count value becomes negative of the INT restriction. What can I do to support my elements? Does Microsoft have any support for using a long for the count? Is there another collection that I should use without that limitation?

Comment: I believe you'll have to reconsider your UI-related architecture. All interfaces in WPF use Int32 as item count/current position. You won't be able to use any existent datagrid control bound to a collection using Int64 for count and indexing, regardless of where it is a virtual or regular collection.
You might want to look into paging or sliding window approach, and display some calculated values to mimic Int64 counter and position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
var list = new List<Data>()

.. load data ...

long items = list.LongCount()
```

That should do the trick... if your backend loads the data!

Comment: Using LongCount will iterate over all elements of the list. It is not intended for this usage.